# Dirty file icon not showing in VSCode

Tags: settings

The bullet icon for a not as yet saved file does not show. Auto Save is not enabled.
I have looked at previous questions, here as well as on the net regarding the issue.
I am using the latest version 1.84.2 for October, 2023
Any idea how to fix this issue?